# Reading blank xls cells through POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to read the empty cells of an xls file and port them to my object xls as null entries. But I'm not identifying these cells as blank. Can someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private boolean lerArquivo(String dir) throws IOException {

    HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    HSSFRow row = null;
    HSSFCell cell = null;
    String path = dir;
    boolean flag = false;

    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(path);

    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (Iterator rit = (Iterator) sheet.rowIterator(); rit.hasNext();) {
        row = (HSSFRow) rit.next();
        for (Iterator cit = (Iterator) row.cellIterator(); cit.hasNext();) {
            cell = (HSSFCell) cit.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                xls.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                xls.add(null);
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    xls.add(cell.getDateCellValue().toString());
                } else {
                    xls.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));

                }
                break;

            default:

            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 01 - 
Hello Gagravarr, thanks for your help.
I Tried your suggest, and read the documentation. 
following what i understood, i changed my code, reaching this:
even this way, the code isn't reading the blank cell. any guess ?

```
for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < 4; rowNum++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        for (int celNum = 0; celNum < row.getLastCellNum(); celNum++) {
            cell = row.getCell(celNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                xls.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: {
                xls.add("");
                break;
            }
            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    xls.add(cell.getDateCellValue().toString());
                } else {
                    xls.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                }
                break;

            default:

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try debugging to see which `Cell`s are returned by the iterator.  It's possible that the cells you expected to be blank simply don't exist.  You may see `Cell`s with column indexes 0, 1, 2, 4 when you expected 3 to be blank, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI has [pretty detailed and explicit documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), you'd be very well advised to read it!

Copying and pasting the example from there, you can see how to handle / detect missing rows and cells, along with blank cells:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you tip. i tried the "RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL", unsuccesfully =/

Comment: What do you mean "unsuccesfully"? It works very successfully in very large numbers of Apache POI unit tests, amongst others! What exactly isn't working?

Comment: sorry, it worked. 
apparently the problem is in xls created by libre office.